# Theory of models. Prove that exists finite set of sentences

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be the set of sentences (formulas without free variables) of the signature $\Sigma $ such that for any algebraic system $\mathfrak{M}$ of signature $\Sigma $ there exists a sentence $ \Phi \in  \Gamma $ that is true on $\mathfrak{M}$.

Show that there exists a finite set $\left \{ \Phi _{1}, \Phi _{2}, ...... \Phi _{n}  \right \} \subseteq \Gamma $ such that the sentence $\left ( \Phi _{1} \vee \left (\Phi _{2} \vee ....  \vee \Phi _{n} \right) ...\right )$ is Is identically true formula.

It sounds intuitively clear, like we have a lot of suggestions and there will always be a true one on some system. but how to show that the true is in a finite set of sentences

Comment: Compactness. ${} $

Comment: What is "Is identically true formula"?

Comment: @Nagase I could use the wrong word, I meant that the formula is true for each signature model S, for any values of the variables

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo how should we use it?? I cant find any finitely consistent set of senteces

Answer (score 1):

Argue by compactness: If what you want to prove is false, $\{\lnot\phi: \phi\in\Gamma\} $ would have a model (contradicting your hypothesis), because each finite subtheory does.

Comment: Ok. when we think that our statment is false, we atr trying to prove the opposite statemant, yes? In my case the opposit is for all sets $\left \{ \Phi _{1}, \Phi _{2}, ...... \Phi _{n}  \right \} \subseteq \Gamma $  sentecne  $\left ( \lnot\Phi _{1} \wedge  \left (\lnot\Phi _{2}  \wedge ....   \wedge \lnot\Phi _{n} \right) ...\right )$s identically true formula. Am i right?

Comment: No, you are not. The opposite is that for all such finite sets the conjunction you indicate is consistent (i.e., it admits a model).

Comment: Generally I meant the same, it would be just a next step in my proof. 
Form my book: algebraic system is a model for set of sentences , if evry element from set is true on algebraic sistem. If conjunction is not identically true formula , how do we get sentences  to be true?

Comment: No you didn't mean the same. The negation of "there is $\{\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n\}\subset\Gamma $ such that $\phi_1\lor\dots\lor\phi_n $ holds in all structures" is not "for all $\{\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n\}\subset\Gamma $, $\lnot\phi_1\land\dots\land\lnot\phi_n $ holds in all structures" but rather "for all $\{\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n\}\subset\Gamma $, $\lnot\phi_1\land\dots\land\lnot\phi_n $ holds in some structure".

Comment: So, we can find a structure, where $\left ( \lnot\Phi _{1} \wedge  \left (\lnot\Phi _{2}  \wedge ....   \wedge \lnot\Phi _{n} \right) ...\right ) $ is true for all finite sets of sentences therefore  for infinitie sets and we get that on the same mode $\Phi $ is true and $ \neg \Phi $ is true.

Comment: Yes, that's the contradiction.